# extjs data reader reading data from nested object of an xml reponse

Tags: xml, extjs

I have xml file with following structure

```
<root>
<o1>
    <p1></p1>
    <p2></p2>
    <p3></p3>
    <o2>
        <p1></p1>
        <o3>
            <p2></p2>
            <p3></p3>
        </o3>
    <o2>
</o1>
</root>
```

I want the model to be loaded only with the p1 p2 and p3 for o1. But the model gets populated with the values inside o2 and o3 instead.
In the reader that I have configured, the root is 'root' and record is o1.
I even tried setting the implicitIncludes property of the reader to false.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because of the Ext.DomQuery.selectNode() method that is used in the conversion function of the model which probably starts parsing from the innermost node and returns the first occurence...

I solved this by overriding the getResponseData() method of the reader. In the overridden method, I removed the inner node of the xml response document i.e. the o2 node and then passed on the document to the readRecords() method as the natural flow is.

Though kind of a workaround but it is fine for me as the inner node is not needed my case.